# How to calculate matrix power using Eigen library?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I need to calculate power of some matrix and then get its eigenvectors. I know that there is method pow() but it is unclear for me how to use it.

For now, my code is:

```
Eigen::Matrix3d mat2 = mat1.pow(0.5);
return getEigenvalues(mat2);
```

Method getEigenvalues() takes Eigen::Matrix type which is not what pow() returns.

Answer (score 2):

That's the wrong order of operations. You first calculate the eigenvalues and next exponentiate those.

The reason is that eigenvalues of the exponentiated matrix are equal to the exponentiated eigenvalues of the original matrix. EDIT: provided the eigenvalues of the original matrix exist.

So, for example, to get the eigenvalues of your matrix `mat2` you write:

```
Eigen::VectorXd ev = getEigenvalues(mat1).unaryExpr([](double d) {return std::pow(d, 0.5);});
```

In case of exponent one-half, you can also better use `std::sqrt`.

---

I forgot to mention that the eigenvectors are identical for the original and the exponentiated matrix, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Functional_calculus) for example.

Comment: But I need eigenvectors not eigenvalues.

Comment: The eigenvectors are identical for the original and the exponentiated matrix. I made an edit.